# Reinstall all sublime text 2 plugins

Tags: sublimetext2, package-control

I'm running Sublime Text 2 with package control installed, as well as a few syntax plugins. But
for no reason at all, whenever I open a rspec file, sublime text gives me this error:

```
Error loading syntax file "Packages/RSpec/RSpec.tmLanguage": Error parsing plist xml: Failed to open file In file "Packages/RSpec/RSpec.tmLanguage"
```

Worked fine yesterday. Googling the error didn't offer much help, so my question is, is there a quick way to reinstall all sublime text plugins using the package control?

Comment: By the way, if anyone else gets here through googling that error message, manually uninstalling and reinstalling the `RSpec (snippets and syntex)` package fixed the problem. Remember to quit and restart sublime though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` and it will open up the `Packages` folder in your filesystem navigator (Explorer, Finder, Nautilus, etc.). Quite Sublime, then delete the `RSpec` folder. When you restart Sublime, Package Control should notice that the package is not present and will automatically reinstall it for you.

Alternatively, you can uninstall and then reinstall the package through Package Control. Open the Command Palette and type `pcr` to bring up `Package Control: Remove Package`. Hit Enter, type `rspec`, then hit enter again to remove it. Restart Sublime, bring up the Command Palette, type `pci` for `Package Control: Install Package`, find RSpec again, and you should be good to go.